# Is there any exception in the rule of making plural nouns ending with "consonant+y"?

Tags: plural-forms

I know nouns end with "consonant+y" becomes "consonant+ies" like "city" becomes "cities" when we make plural forms.
Is there any exception like "piano" can't be "pianoes" because it comes from "pianoforte"?

Comment: piano ends in a vowel so it has nothing to do with city/cities/country/countries//misery/miseries, etc.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. But you spell like potatoes, heroes and pianos, photos. It's because photo comes from photograph. I would like to know if there is this kind of exception about nouns end with "consonant+ies".

Comment: Sorry, but I am not doing this. Too much **work**. Money can be moneys or monies.

Comment: I'm afraid your argument is invalid, Chance: _soprano_, _alto_, _concerto_, _armadillo_ are not shortenings, but take plurals in _-os_ (though some of them have alternative plural in _-oes_ according to Wikipedia. I don't think there is a reliable rule, but it seems to me that most words in _-o_ have a plural in _-os_, except for some words that were adopted into English long ago and have lost any sense of being foreign, like _potato_ and _hero_,

Comment: @Lambie How is "money" relevant to OP's question?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Because it is a plural with ies and is not preceded by a consonant + y.

Comment: @Lambie Oh. OP was asking about words ending in consonant + "y", so I wasn't sure what point you were trying to make by using a different situation.

Comment: I'm sorry. Now I understand that I wanna know a noun ending with "consonant+y" which is not pronounced "ai".

Comment: @Colin Fine You're right. Now I know that loan words don't follow the rule. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. As one example, the plural of **flyby** is **flybys,** as [Merriam-Webster confirms](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flyby).

Comment: ["Why"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/why) is another example. And of course many proper nouns, such as ["Emmy"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Emmy).

Comment: @alphabet Thank you for your answer. If you knew, could you tell me any nouns ending with "consonant+y" which is not pronounced "ai"?